# Excel Runtime error 13

Tags: c#, excel, vba, com

I've gone through various posts and can't figure out my problem.

I have a COM object that builds and a Excel.Range of data and hands this back to an Excel macro. This is then set to a Variant and then it's used to populate a range. Quite simple and it was working, but now it's not I can't figure out why.

The C# is passing back the correct data by setting the Variant, which is causing my error.

Any ideas?

The code is below:

```
Dim rangeData As Variant
rangeData = factory.Build(buildType)

Worksheets(sheet).Activate
Worksheets(sheet).range("A1:Z10000").Value = rangeData
```

The factory object is my C# COM object.

Answer (score 0):

Your rangeData should probably be an array of Variants, if your COM object returns an array.

Try to declare rangeData like this (notice the brackets):

```
Dim rangeData() as Variant
```

Comment: Might have been useful if I#'d have mentioned the C# returns and Excel.Range object. So setting the variable to an array didn't make a difference. I've also tried setting the Variant variable to a range object.

Comment: Hi, its Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range

Comment: Then you may want to try the copy method of the range : `rangeData.Copy destination:=Worksheets("sheet").Range("A1:Z10000")` - you need to declar erangeData as Range for this

Comment: I don't think you can declare a Range variable in VBA explicitly. An older version of the code appears to work, going to try and work out what the difference is, but the Sub is tiny so not sure how well this will work.

Comment: Simpler, without using a temporary variable, use the copy method on the returned range object : `factory.Build(buildType).Copy destination:=Worksheets("sheet").Range("A1:Z10000")`

Comment: I've done the following, put the range from c# into a range object and am trying to use this. Getting the date in the new Range variable is fine and I can get the column and row counts, but trying to use the copy method throws' Copy Method of Range class failed'. I am using the following: newRange.Copy Destination:=Worksheets(sheet).range("A1:A50"). The range being constructed is 26x3 cells.

Comment: I changed the C# layer to hand back an array instead of a Range and this then worked. Thanks for the suggestions.